# How to make a call to an executable from another executable/Python script on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I was doing the same on windows with `os.system("filename.exe")`

But on mac, pyinstaller is creating unix executable and have no extension to it.

I've tried `os.system("filename")` which didn't work.

I've also tried `os.system("./filename")` which worked on python script but when I make executable file it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried doing `os.system("bash filename")`?

Comment: I just tried a script. It `os.system("./filename")` works for me. How are you converting to executable.

Comment: @Grayrigel Using pyinstaller to convert it to unix executable.

Comment: I've solved it by adding that executable on this executable using add-data on pyinstaller

Answer (score -1):

if the executable is python just import the file and it will run the main block
assume this is `a.py`

```py
print('hello')
```

and in your python code do

```py
import a
```

the output will be

```
hello
```